# Raspberry Pi Air Display

Tags: linux

recently I've discovered air display for various configurations (mac+pc, pc+pc, etc.). I've been thinking about doing the same with raspberry pi connected to my tv. Although air display isn't available for linux. Do you have any ideas about achieving same experience with rpi? I've googled a little bit and found synergy, but it only shares mouse and keyboard for many computers and it's fine but i also want rpi to run extended monitor from my windows pc.
Thanks.

Comment: What does air display do?

Comment: http://avatron.com/apps/air-display ? Why will vnc not solve your problem? This sounds more like vnc or remotr desktop.